# When using ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) for a copy constructor I get two errors

Tags: java, arraylist, copy-constructor, containment

```
public ListArrayListBased(ListArrayListBased < E > var) 

{

items = new ArrayList < E> (ArrayList(ListArrayListBased 
        < ? extends E > var));

}
```

Using this line of code gives me two errors.

1. Wildcard is not allowed at this location.
2. Syntax Error on token "ListArrayListBased", :: expected after token.

I was able to fix the second one by putting :: after ListArrayListBased but I have no clue what that did or how it worked. I am looking more for an explanation on the errors then on the solutions to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to do here.  If you just want `items` to be a copy of your list argument, use `items = new ArrayList<>(var);`.  (Also, `var` is a language keyword as of Java 10, so you will want to avoid using it as a variable name.)

Comment: What is `ArrayList(ListArrayListBased< ? extends E > var)` supposed to be? It's not a method call. Or a method declaration. Or a cast. Or anything else I can think of.

Comment: When I use the items = ArrayList<>(var) i get an error, "The constructor ArrayList(ListArrayListBased)<E> is undefined.

Comment: Btw, don't name variables `var`. Aside from it being a terribly vague name, it's a (sort of) keyword in Java 11+.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy constructor, and you're trying to assign the `items` member variable, which is presumably the list inside your class.

So, copy the `items` list from `var`:

```
items = new ArrayList<>(var.items);
```